# c++ the value of a double

Tags: c++

Given the following declaration:

```
double x;
```

What is the value of `x`?

**Is my answer correct?**

The value of `x` is: *plus or minus 10 to 308th (limited to ~12 significant digits)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your answer is not correct. What thought process led you to that answer? Where might you have gone wrong?

---

Given the proliferation of "answers" on this question, I'm just going to come out and state it. The answer is that the value of x is **undefined**. It's an uninitialized value. If you try to read the value, in practice you'll get garbage (i.e. you'll get whatever bit pattern was in that memory location, reinterpreted as a `double`). But it's not as simple as that. Since the value is undefined, the optimization pass of the compiler is actually free to make choices based on the undefined value that it could not have made if the variable had *any* defined value. Any attempts to use an uninitialized variable can produce unexpected results, and is certainly a programming error.

---

There is one caveat, as I alluded to in my comment. If this declaration happens at the top level (or is modified with the `static` keyword) then the value becomes simply `0.0`.

Comment: I suppose I chose that answer because I assumed that the value must be within a range.

Comment: @RPM: First, a semantic point: "plus or minus NUM" tells me it's either positive NUM or negative NUM. That's better expressed as "zero plus or minus NUM" which makes it clear this is an error range. Second, there are non-numeric values that double can take, including +Inf, -Inf, and NaN. Third, what does the spec actually say the value of `x` is? The answer to this question is actually the same *regardless* of the type of `x`.

Comment: @RPM: Also, I'm assuming here that `double x` is a local variable in a function. The answer is actually different if it's defined at the top level.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `T x;` you *default-initialize* the variable `x`, and for a fundamental type `T` such as `double` this means that no initialization happens at all, the variable has *indeterminate value* (cf. 8.5), and *reading* the variable `x` before writing to it is simply **undefined behaviour** (cf. the note in 17.6.3.3/2).

So it's much worse than just getting an unknown value - rather, your entire program becomes non-deterministic at the point of invoking undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on where the variable is defined.

```
#include <iostream>

double x;
int main(){
    double y;

    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Different rules apply to global and local variables.

`x` will be initialized to zero.
`y`, as everyone else has stated, could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `x` could be anything. It's undefined behavior to access the value, and so you could even get a value `double` can't contain. If `x` has static storage then it is defined, and will be initialized to `0.0`.

In practice it will be a pseudo random assortment of bits. Not really random as it's left over from what was previously in the same location in memory. So yes, it will be within your range, along with infinities and NaN as those are also doubles.

Comment: This is a homework problem. Just handing him the solution isn't going to help.

Comment: Not to mention the explanation "it could also be infinity and NaN" implies that's *all* it could also be, which isn't true.

Comment: @Kevin So (at)Borealid says my answer is correct, but you say it is not. I am confused. Who do I take advice from?

Comment: @RPM: Borealid is using the same thought process you are, which is to try and figure out all the meanings that various bit patterns crammed into a `double` container would have. That's not actually the correct answer. See ildjarn's reply to Borealid.

Answer (score -3):

You are correct.

The value is uninitialized and may contain anything resident in memory. Double precision is 53 effective bits, so your range is approximately right. I didn't check your precision but it's not exact since the level of accuracy is compressed around zero.

It's worth mentioning that there's also positive and negative infinity, plus `NaN`, and finally negative zero (yes, negative zero!). There are bitstrings which aren't even IEEE floating-point numbers which `x` could contain too :-).

Comment: No, he's not correct -- an uninitialized double may not have any valid value at all, that's completely implementation-specific.

Comment: @ildjarn: I said that in my last sentence.

Comment: @ildjarn: excepting infinities, the value of `x` will be neither greater than what he specified as a maximum not less than what he specified as a minimum. If the number is not outside a range, it is within it. And if he does math with an invalid value, the results are likely to be interesting but not impossible.

This is a matter of definitions, not understanding.

Comment: And if the uninitialized memory does not contain a valid double value then it is neither in or outside of a range, it is merely undefined. Additionally there's `NaN` which of course is also neither in or outside of a range.

Comment: @Borealid: You're wrong. The value is undefined. In practice, if you successfully read this value, you'll end up with garbage, but the optimizer is actually free to make choices based on the fact that the value is undefined that it could not have made if the value had any definition at all. So it's actually wrong to even claim the variable has a value that falls within the domain of values of a `double`.

Comment: Aren't these called "trap representations" or is that something else?